# spread out an item list by the quantity column in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

[image]

How could I turn the left item list into right hand side list, and the ID column generate automatically will be great, thank you so much for solve my problem

Comment: If the answer below has solved your issue, please check it off as an answer, to help others with a similar question.  If not, please clarify your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V5UW20fqaAThCHX0inYrMt8AjQmflfZiCmk-G7HxAUM/edit?usp=sharing

Formula is:

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(FLATTEN(IFERROR(
  SPLIT(
    REPT(A2:A15 &  "~", VLOOKUP(A2:A15,A2:B15,2,0)),
    "~")
  ))),"select * where Col1 is not null",0)
```

The FLATTEN function, to flatten a range into one column, is apparently undocumented, but you can Google its use.

Let me know if this works for you.

Also, your input data was in alphabetical order.  If this won't always be the case, the query could be modified, changing the last line to 
"select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1".

Comment: I'm pretty new on here.  Could someone let me know if I did something wrong in my answer post, or is it just not a very good answer, since it got a downvote from the first person looking?  Thanks.

Comment: my input data is not alphabetical order, i put that way to make easy understanding.